# Building a permissions table with Prisma 2 and PostgreSQL to authorize users based on permission level?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, graphql, prisma

If you've used Google Docs, Notion, Figma, etc. One thing they have in common is a robust permissions scheme.

Using Notion as an example, here are some ways you can share

- Invite everyone who is in the workspace
- Share to the web (fully public)
- Share via email

Each sharing method has permission levels (https://www.notion.so/Sharing-permissions-524c32ac63dc424a842891ace7a99bf8#73fc49683ef64589a1a6ed5fdcb67adc)

- Full access
- Can edit
- Can comment
- Can view

In my project, I am using Prisma 2 with GraphQL (GraphQL Nexus). Here is a good guide that I am following https://www.prisma.io/blog/graphql-directive-permissions-authorization-made-easy-54c076b5368e it talks about `directive permissions`.

My question is how do I create permissions based on the owners desire? It would seem I would need to create a new Table in the DB to manage the permissions.

This example showcases what to do when you already have a role field on the User model. Meaning a user can either be a `Manager` or not from directly interacting with the User model.

```
const Query = {
  vehicles: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
    const vehicles = await context.db.query.vehicles({
      where: { dealership: args.id },
    })
    const user = getUser(context)
    return vehicles.map(vehicle => ({
      ...vehicle,
      costBasis: user && user.role.includes(`MANAGER`) ? vehicle.costBasis : null,
      numberOfOffers: user ? vehicle.numberOfOffers : null,
    }))
  },
}
```

In the case where there could be many different access levels on many different documents, it would not make sense to update the `User` model...

What would make sense is you create a file with id `123`, then as the owner you can specify who can access the document and what level their permissions are. So you would want to offload that onto a new Table.

```
-------------------------------
id  | docid | userid | level
-------------------------------
909 | 123   | 300    | "Read"
899 | 123   | 310    | "Write"
```

Then from here, you would allow the mutation to run from the users' request, check the document id the user is trying to gain access to, then inside the permissions table check to see if the user id exists by looking up all records that match the document id, then you would pull the permissions level and return the appropriate data.

Am I thinking about this correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Great question!

Here's a great article on [How to Auth: Securing your GraphQL Permissions](https://dev.to/mandiwise/how-to-auth-securing-your-graphql-api-with-confidence-14j) that explains how to implement permissions on your GraphQL API.

If you run into any issues, don't hesitate to let us know.